# Android app shows in low zoom

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, mobile-application

I created simple android app using phonegap and deployed to playstore. unfortunately once i deployed the app to store, it displays in a very small area like the whole screen is zoomed to 10% or even less than that. What may be the issue? I have default viewport settings etc.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Weather Application</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: put some code here from `index.html` to get more idea about the issue

Comment: Assuming there would be issue in head part, I updated head part code in the qiestion.

Comment: Any reason to keep the `user-scalable=yes`, also on which device have you tested? Did you test the signed APK before deploying to app store?

Comment: By default i got user-scalable=no. I am just trying to change this to see if that is the issue. I tried installing the signed apk on my device and it also shows the same issue.

Comment: have you tried on any other device? perhaps on a different emulator like https://www.manymo.com/

Comment: tried but the issue is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88948/discussion-between-dhaval-and-chandana).

Answer (score 0):

@Chandana,
you have too much in your header. Reduce the declaration in your `viewport`, then add what you need.

Start with this, add one item at a time.

```
<meta name="viewport" width=device-width />
```

Jesse